# Die Bedeutung des Worts "Ermangelung"

Tags: meaning

[Hier](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ermangelung) findet man die Bedeutungserklärung für *Ermangelung*.

Das Wort "Ermangelung" wird wieder zur Bedeutungserklärung benutzt. Deshalb verstehe ich nicht die Bedeutung.

Was bedeutet der Ausdruck "in Ermangelung eines Besseren"?

Ich habe das in den zwei Sätzen gefunden:

1. ["etwas, womit man sich in Ermangelung eines Besseren behelfen muss; Notlösung; Provisorium"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Behelf)
2. ["in Ermangelung eines Besseren begnügte sie sich mit der Kopie"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ermangelung)

Comment: Duden-Online hat normalerweise keine Bedeutungserklärungen, soweit ich sehen kann auch nicht für das Wort *Ermangelung*, auch wenn es da die irreführende Überschrift **Bedeutung** gibt. Dafür würde ich eher Wiktionary verwenden: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_Ermangelung

Comment: Wenn Deine Muttersprache nicht Deutsch ist, könntest Du es mit einem Wörterbuch versuchen. [Leo bspw. hat für Deutsch/Englisch sehr gute Übersetzungen für *in Ermangelung*](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/ermangelung)

Comment: Auch etwas geeigneter als der Duden: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ermangelung

Comment: "The question neither elaborates why such a **resource did not help** nor is it obvious.." - ich finde die Frage muss daher nicht geschlossen werden. Ich habe geskippt, weil ich mich noch nicht mit der "üblichen Herangehensweise" auf german.se auskenne. Vielleicht kann mir jemand weiterhelfen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In Ermangelung von* ist eine Wendung im [wikipedia: Nominalstil](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalstil), die bedeutet

> weil jemand etwas nicht hat.

Für Bedeutung und Beispiele siehe [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ermangelung).

Nominalstil wird häufig in offiziellen Texten verwendet (oder in Texten, die so klingen sollen), ist aber schlechter verständlich.

*In Ermangelung von etwas Besserem* ist nur **ein** Beispiel für die Verwendung, aber  keine feste Wendung mit eigener Bedeutung.

Answer (score 3):

> in Ermangelung eines Besseren

Der Mangel an etwas Besserem, aber als *abstraktes Konstrukt*.

der Mangel - die **Ermangelung**

[dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/german-english/in+Ermangelung.html) schlägt *in the absence of a better alternative* als Übersetzung vor.